# SELECT INTO with BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

MySQL/Oracle/Teradata has `SELECT ... INTO FROM ...` to get value from a table and assign them to variable(s). How can I do this with BigQuery?

```sql
SELECT 
    c1, c2, c3, ...
INTO 
    @v1, @v2, @v3,...
FROM 
    table_name
WHERE 
    condition;
```

Comment: for people looking to SELECT INTO a table, which is not valid sql in bq, the bq way is to run your SQL statement and then save the results as a table

Comment: @smoore4 could your scenario be solved by `INSERT INTO <table> SELECT ...`?

Comment: yes, you can do INSERT SELECT (note it is not INSERT INTO).  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The counterpart in BigQuery is a `SET` statement getting value from a subquery.

See this example:

```sql
SET (v1, v2, v3) = (SELECT AS STRUCT c1, c2, c3 FROM table_name WHERE condition LIMIT 1)
```

It behaves exactly the same as the query in question.

See more examples from [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#examples_1).

Comment: How would you use this further? As BQ doesn't support running multiple queries.

Comment: The ability to use scripting, stored procedures, and temporary tables is now in Beta. See [more](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#October_03_2019)

Comment: glad yo corrected your answer - but you still missing `LIMIT 1` - in case if sub-query returns more then one row

Comment: The (SELECT ...) syntax enforces that 0..1 row is returned from select or there is error notifying user about its usage. The example is to be on par with what's in the question, where mistake can also be made to render an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way would be as below:

```
SET (v1, v2, v3) = (SELECT AS STRUCT c1, c2, c3 FROM table_name WHERE condition LIMIT 1)
```