# why does Stored procedure not return the 'Out' parameter in bigquery?

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I am writing below Stored Procedure in BigQuery but not sure where did I do wrong.
The 'Out' Parameter does not return anything.

Stored Procedure:

```
create procedure if not exists test.GetNumTherapistSessions(
    in LastNamee string,
    out NumSessione int64
)
begin 
    select count(s.SessionNum) as NumSession from test.Session s 
    inner join test.Therapist t on s.TherapistID=t.TherapistID
    where t.LastName=LastNamee;
end
```

and Here is how I declare the output parameter and how to call it:

```
declare NumSession int64;
call test.GetNumTherapistSessions("Risk",NumSession);
```

Here is the output:
[image]

So far everything seems right, but when I select the NumSession, it returns Null:

```
select NumSession;
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: you can use `select count(s.SessionNum) into  NumSession`

Comment: please tell me if that solved your problem

Comment: where should I try this? in SP?

Comment: yes just add `into NumSession` such as `select count(s.SessionNum) into NumSessione from test.Session s 
    inner join test.Therapist t on s.TherapistID=t.TherapistID
    where t.LastName=LastNamee;`

Comment: Thank you, I think Sergey said the same thing. I am going to give it try now

Comment: ok I will insert it as an answer too if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SET NumSessione = (select count...);`

```
create procedure if not exists test.GetNumTherapistSessions(
    in LastNamee string,
    out NumSessione int64
)
begin 
    SET NumSessione = (
      select count(s.SessionNum) as NumSession from test.Session s 
      inner join test.Therapist t on s.TherapistID=t.TherapistID
      where t.LastName=LastNamee
    );
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works fine. Can you please explain why we should add the Set? I assumed that when we defined the variables, it will automatically assign the output of statement in Begin...End into the out Parameter

Comment: It is just as it is. Example from Google: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures

Comment: So there is another answer someone else gives. He uses 'into' , but I tried it and it does not work. Do you think using 'set' as you suggested is the only way?

Comment: it is seems that bigquery don't have INTO so I will suggest this as a correct answer and I will modify my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in this docs of bigquery [Link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax) you can use `SET` to assign any values you need to a specific Variables.

**Note** that bigquery don't have `SELECT INTO` statement inside procedure.

Examples:

```
SET (value1, value2, value3) = (SELECT AS STRUCT c1, c2, c3 FROM table_name WHERE condition)
```

From this answer:[select-into-with-bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245225/select-into-with-bigquery)

Another Example:

```
UPDATE dataset.Inventory
SET quantity = quantity +
  (SELECT quantity FROM dataset.NewArrivals
   WHERE Inventory.product = NewArrivals.product),
    supply_constrained = false
WHERE product IN (SELECT product FROM dataset.NewArrivals)
```

Another examples can be found here: [Link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures)

Comment: I see, Thank you. I assumed the begin...end will assign the value into the Out parameter automatically but it seems it does not do this on bigquery, right?

Comment: yes because you can also have multiple outputs so you need to assign every select value into whatever output you want by using set or select into, you can find more examples for that inside those links [Link_1](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-select-into/) and [link_2](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/377/Syllabus/6-StoredProc/variables.html)

Comment: hope those links will help you to understand well.

Comment: I see, thanks . but it does not accept 'into' there. it shows: Syntax error: Expected ";" but got keyword INTO