# SELECT INTO clause in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am getting error while running the below code. I did SELECT INTO in PLSQL but not understanding how to do same in bigquery.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `linear-charmer-344806.2143.Test`(name STRING, OUT id STRING)
    begin 
    set (id) =(select roll from `linear-charmer-344806.2143.Employee` 
    where name = "Triparna");
    end;
```

Comment: You can follow this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax) to write the code.

Comment: You need set and not OUT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66705753/why-does-stored-procedure-not-return-the-out-parameter-in-bigquery

Comment: @Samuel, with belw code it worked:set (id) =(select as struct dept from `linear-charmer-344806.2143.Employee` 
where name = name);

Comment: Please check the `SET` documentation on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#set)

Answer (score 1):

you should have either scalars on both sides or structs on both sides

for example

scalars

```
set id =(select roll from `linear-charmer-344806.2143.Employee` 
where name = "Triparna");
```

or structs

```
set (id) =(select as struct roll from `linear-charmer-344806.2143.Employee` 
where name = "Triparna");
```

In your case, looks like former option is the way to go